# How to run SQL Script in Azure Data Factory v2?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

There is NO Sql Script activity in Azure Data Factory V2. So how can I create a stored proc, a schema in a database? What are my options?

Comment: There is no way to run SQL Script currently in Azure Data Factory. You should be able to create a Stored Proc directly in the database where you want to run it and execute using ADF "Stored Procedure" activity.

Comment: Now there is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71339898/5070879

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I agree that the absence of something like "Execute SQL task" of SSIS is bumming. I normally use a "LookUp" activity as I don't like to create procedures for simple tasks which could be a one liner command. The only constraint of lookup activity is that it needs some sort of output result set. So what I do when I need to run an update statement is something like this:

[image]

The dummy query `select 0 id` "feeds" the data to the Lookup activity and thus it is able to run the command set on database.

**EDIT**: At the time of first writing this, I found no other way than this and the answer came out of my own personal experience. However, Microsoft did add a "Script Activity" (refer Lukasz's answer) later which is surely the better way to go right now.

Answer (score 9):

1. There is a [preCopyScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server#sql-server-as-sink) property. You could put your script there. It will be executed before each run.
2. You could use [store procedure activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure) as Summit mentioned.
3. You could also create a [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity).

Answer (score 6):

It is possible using **[Script activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-script)**:

> **Using the script activity, you can execute common operations with Data Manipulation Language (DML), and Data Definition Language (DDL).** DML statements like SELECT, UPDATE, and INSERT let users retrieve, store, modify, delete, insert and update data in the database. DDL statements like CREATE, ALTER and DROP allow a database manager to create, modify, and remove database objects such as tables, indexes, and users.

[image]

<sup>Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/media/transform-data-using-script/inline-script.png</sup>

Related: [Execute SQL statements using the new 'Script' activity in Azure Data Factory and Synapse Pipelines](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/execute-sql-statements-using-the-new-script-activity-in-azure/ba-p/3239969)

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide another option, I will share how I use to do it.

1. Create a "Stored Procedure" Activity
2. On Settings at "Stored procedure name", mark Edit, and type: sp_executesql
3. Under Stored procedure parameters, add a new parameter called "statement", and in "Value" put your SQL command.

This works with dynamic content as well. Reference about this procedure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Regards