# Delete data from destination tables before running copy data activity

Tags: sql, oracle, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a pipeline that moves data between some Oracle databases. I have successfully created and tested the [copy data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) activities. My problem is I want to empty the destination tables before the "copy" runs and I can't see a way to do that (right now it appends data to the tables).

At first I tried using the [Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure) activity, but that only supports SQL Server-related sources. None of the other activities offered by data factory work for this use case. Even a generic "execute SQL" activity could work for me, but nothing like that appears to be available.

EDIT: I have posted an answer below, but it's not ideal. Please post an answer if you think you have a better solution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use "TRUNCATE TABLE xxx" in pre-copy script. (Truncate is faster than Delete)

Also, to your point, there is no "Execute SQL task", but as a hack, we can use a "Lookup" activity to execute ad-hoc scripts. Link to one of my previous answers on the same : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59422740/2993606

Comment: Thanks, this could be promising. I'll try this tomorrow and if it works for my use case I'll upvote you and give you the bounty.

Comment: This works, thank you. I would still rather have a generic "Execute SQL" activity, but that's up to Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a slightly hacky solution. There is a configuration in the Sink part of the Copy Data activity called **Pre-copy script**. The documentation says to use it for manipulating the incoming data so I thought it would only work on the incoming data, but it's actually SQL that's executed on the target database (seemingly in a transaction, which is committed)

So basically, this works:

[image: sql in copy data activity]

I'm not a huge fan of this solution, because it's hard to configure the flow. I would have preferred a separate activity so I could prepare success/failure options, while with this, the whole "Copy Data" activity will fail. Please post an answer if you have a better idea!

Answer (score 0):

I have always used a Stored Procedure to clear table data as part of my pipelines. I do this because I usually have a specific where clause for the data [that typically lines up with a table partition] rather than truncating the entire table.

As an alternative to the Copy activity, you can use a Data Flow (ADFDF) activity. ADFDF Sink settings show you can truncate the table:

[image]

This screenshot is for a SQLDW Sink, so I don't know if the ADFDF Sink for Oracle permits this or not.

Comment: It does not. I mention this in my question, "Stored Procedure" activity is not supported for Oracle Database linked service.

Comment: Sorry if my post was not clear - my screen shot was NOT for stored procedure, or Copy activity, but for using a Data Flow activity. Post edited for clarity.

Comment: The answer of @SouravA works for my use case. But I'll take a look at this too, thanks for your effort.

Comment: No problem - I would have suggested the same as he did, but you had said the pre-script was not ideal so I wanted to give you an alternative :-)

Comment: My problem with the "Pre copy script" was that it was not a separate activity, and I wanted to check its success/failuler separately. For example, if the "pre copy" failed, that would make the whole "Copy Data" activity fail, and I didn't want that. Using the "Lookup" is I suppose equally hacky, but at least I can handle its failure separately.