# Can we use ADF Lookup activity perform INSERT operation on SNOWFLAKE table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have created new dataset using snowflake connector and used the same as source dataset in lookup activity.

Then I am trying to INSERT the record into snowflake using following query.
'INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TABLE VALUES('TEST',1,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'TEST'-- (all values are passed)

Result: **The row getting inserted into snowflake but my pipeline got failed stating the below error.**

Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcInvalidQueryString,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The following ODBC Query is not valid: 'INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TABLE VALUES('TEST',1,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'TEST');'

Could you please share you advise or anylead to solve this problem.

Thanks.
Rajesh

Comment: Lookup will not be able to insert data, lookup is used to retrieve data. I would suggest you to use either a stored procedure activity or Query option in a copy activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup, as the name suggests, is for searching and retrieving data, not for inserting. However, you can enclose your INSERT code in a procedure and execute it using the Lookup activity.

[image]

However, I strongly **do not recommend such an action**, remember that when inserting data into Snowflake, you create at least one micro-partition with a size of 16MB, if you insert one line at a time, the performance will be terrible and the data will take up a disproportionate amount of space. Remember Snowlfake is not a transaction database (! OLTP).

Instead, it's better to save all the records in an intermediate file and then import the entire file in one move.

Comment: Just to extend: Lookup activity is no longer necessary. ADF v2 supports natively SQL Script activity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71339898/5070879

Comment: Thanks Michael.
I have chosen Lookup activity to execute my Stored procedure and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use the lookup activity to perform operations other than selects, it just HAS to have an output. I've gotten around it with a postgres database doing create tables, truncates, one off inserts by just concatenating a

select current_date;

after the main query.

Note, the sql script activity will definitely be better for this, we are waiting on postgres support in that though.

Answer (score 0):

I had same ODBC issue when I used script activity to run the Proc.Seems to work if you define script parameters which are required in script parameters section in settings .

Comment: Provide parameter while calling in script query. PROCNAME(parameter type) and also mention cript parameters which are required in script parameters section in settings below query window

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).