# Script activity vs lookup activity on ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a benefit of using Script activity over Lookup? I know that there are limits with Lookup like being able to return no more than 1 MB of data. Does Script activity have any improvements in terms of price/performance/feature? I could not find many references online.

BTW, Lookup *can* be used to run not only `SELECT`, but `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `TRUNCATE` etc. too, [albeit seeming like a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59422740/2993606).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: comparison from MS blog]

[From the MS blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/execute-sql-statements-using-the-new-script-activity-in-azure/ba-p/3239969) :

- Lookup activity does not block modify operations, but it is not recommended to use lookup activity to modify data.

** Multiple queries can be executed successfully in lookup activity for some connectors but cannot retrieve full result.

Note: Be careful when returning result sets, since the activity output is limited to 5000 row/ 2MB size. If you are logging through your SQL script (Print statements), you can work around the limit by choosing your Storage account for logging.

For more details, refer [script activity documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-script).